# How do I tell CodeIgniter ActiveRecord NOT to escape my insert and update queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I need to send some xml that I trust (I wrote it) to my mysql database.

ActiveRecord escapes a lot of my XML. When I pull it out of the database, I am not using CodeIgniter, so I need clean XML in the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read function [set](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) in active record. Below is the snippet from the documentation.

> This function enables you to set values for inserts or updates.
>   set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that
>   will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE. To illustrate
>   the difference, here is set() used both with and without the escape
>   parameter.

```
$this->db->set('field', 'field+1', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('mytable');
// gives INSERT INTO mytable (field) VALUES (field+1)

$this->db->set('field', 'field+1');
$this->db->insert('mytable');
// gives INSERT INTO mytable (field) VALUES ('field+1')
```